# in-app purchase with server

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I want to implement an in-app purchasing mechanism that supports both Google checkout and PayPal for purchasing virtual items in one of my Android apps. I read both references of these mechanisms but I still have one question as to what is the correct way to handle such purchases.
The issue is that i'd like to manage a call to my own server as part of the purchase transaction and in case that call fails to cancel/rollback the entire transaction. If I first perform the purchasing transaction and only when its confirmed I call my own service, what should I do if it fails? If I first call my service and than try to handle the transaction and it fails I need to rollback my call (and what happens if the rollback fails? ??)

What is the correct way to manage it? Is there some way to create a multi-phase transaction that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use the `Google Checkout` Mechanism provided for InApp Billing than `PayPal` SDK as it is the best way for getting the error responses of the transaction as well as `RESTORE TRANSACTIONS` if the app is deleted from the device and reinstalled again. Google Provides the Asynchronous Broadcast Notifications during the App Billing transactions. Purchase Types can be divided into Managed(per user account) and UnManaged.

Google provides the information here: [In App Billing Overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) as below:

**1.Some in-app billing implementations may also use a private remote server to deliver content or validate transactions, but a remote server is not required to implement in-app billing.**

**2.A remote server can be useful if you are selling digital content that needs to be delivered to a user's device, such as media files or photos.**

**3.You might also use a remote server to store users' transaction history or perform various in-app billing security tasks, such as signature verification.**

**4.Although you can handle all security-related tasks in your application, performing those tasks on a remote server is recommended because it helps make your application less vulnerable to security attacks.**

So, Finally I would like to recommend you the Google InApp Billing Implementation over other third-party payment process.

Comment: Although this answer is not perfect for what I am looking for, it's the closest to it... Still looking for a solution to allow both mechanisms (Google Checkout and PayPal) with my application server as part of the same transaction

Comment: can you help me please..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431145/how-to-download-in-app-purchase-item-from-our-server-android-and-ios

Answer (score 3):

I've never used Google Checkout before, only PayPal.

What you might be looking for is the PayPal Payments Pro SDK.

This lets your server become the face of the paying transaction (and not the PayPal site like the normal Checkout express).

You need to implement a 2-phase commit mechanism.

I can recommend two different approaches:

a) You could start the purchase process on your server and leave it in a middle "uncommited" status in the database. 
You call PayPal from your server so PP can process your call, and when you have the response from PP, and if the response means that the payment was accepted, you commit your purchase.  The problem with this approach is that your application need to take a decition of completing or rejecting the transaction at that point, and that is not how a real world purchase transaction might behave. PayPal might sometimes response something different than just plain OK/Error, the payment can be pending, or it can be OK with warning.

b) Even more reliable is letting PayPal notify you about the payment status.

You make the same flow as described before with a change. Once PayPal processes the payment and give you a **positive** answer, you store the transaction ID in your database but don't commit anything. Only tell the user that the transaction was completed.

As part of the call to the PayPal server, there is a parameter that you can use, that parameter is called the IPN Listener URL.

IPN means Instant payment notification, is a call back to **your server**, originated by PayPal, in which your application will get instant information about your payment status.

This is really important as a pending transactions might become accepted or rejected. Even an accepted transaction might be rollback-ed by you or by a claim suited by your purchaser to PayPal.

Let me know if you need more information on how to implement the PP IPN Listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but since I'm probably going to use the PayPal SDK for Android, the transaction is handled by the SDK and all I get is an OK/Cancel/Error indication on the device, and not even on the server. If I go with server-side transaction, I miss all the benefits of using a native SDK for Android within the application which is much more user-friendly

Comment: @muzikant sure it's the best to use the native SDK for Android, but that doesn't mean you can't also configure your PayPal merchant account for using IPN. Since you can configure this parameter as a global setting for all the transactions in your api account, this IPN functionality will help you on having a fail safe mechanism in case your first commit mechanism fails.

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably try it out. Still looking for a solution using Google Checkout though...

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking for a way of implementing a payment method handled by Google you can find a detailed description on how to implement **Android Market In-app Billing** here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, It's not possible to "rollback" transaction. I think Google's logic as simple as possible: if you do have product (added to Developer Console) than you do can sell it.
When Google's market service tells you PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED you should confirm transaction. Otherwise the app will receive PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED till it is not confirmed, but the fact is that user already charged. And you can not rollback this transaction.
If your server can reject transaction, you should implement additional logic for such cases, for example:

- check if the product available BEFORE starting purchase;

  if product available - use "booking" for the product to be sure it is exist when purchase is done;

  and so on;

  otherwise you should tell user to contact support for refund.