# How to download In-app purchase item from our server android and iOS

Tags: android, iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I need some information about in app purchase app.
I want to work on Inapp purchase app for android and iPhone both.
I just need to know few things about InApp system.

After reading documentation and stack-overflow, i come to know that it is possible to upload Inapp purchase data item (like videos,music) on our own server and we just need to manage purchase item list on google play for android or app store for iPhone. I just need to know that after purchase item what are the "strings or values or data or response" app server sends us like "purchase_item_id or username_id" so that i can send this value to my own server to download the particular purchase item from my server to particular user.

Thank you for your valuable time!
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's In App Purchase documentation has all the answers you need. When you create an In App Purchase on iTunes Connect, Apple will assign that purchase a product id. You can use this product id to know what to download from the server if the In App Purchase is successful.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html